# What's wrong with this c++ code?

Tags: c++, formula, quadratic

I've made a few changes here but I'm still not getting what I expect to get. For example,  when I substitute a for 1, b for 2 and c for 2, I should get -1+i and -1-i but when I run code it gives me -0.73205+i and - 2.73205+i. How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a, b, c, disc, x1, x2, root1, root2, imrt1, imrt2;
    char i;
    cout<<"Enter a, b and c ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c ;


    if(disc == 0.0 && b == 0.0)
        cout<<"The equation is degenerate and has no real roots. \n";
    else if(a == 0.0)
        cout<<"The equation has one real root x = "<< -c/b <<endl;

    else
    {
        disc =  pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c;
        if (disc > 0.0)
        {
            disc = sqrt(disc);
            root1 = (-b+disc)/(2*a);
            root2 = (-b-disc)/(2*a);
            cout<<"The two real roots are "<<root1<<" and "<<root2<<endl;
        }

        else if(disc < 0.0)
        disc =  pow(b,2.0)+4*a*c;
        disc = sqrt(disc);
        imrt1 = (-b+disc)/(2*a);
        imrt2 = (-b-disc)/(2*a);
        cout<<"The two imaginary roots are "<<imrt1<<"+i"<<" and <<imrt2<<"+i"<<"\n";

        else
            cout<<"Both roots are equal to "<<-b/(2*a)<<endl;
    }//End of compound statement for the outer else

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please indent your code with 4 spaces to make it look like code.

Comment: please read the editing and posting guidelines. this code is nearly impossible to read!

Comment: Proper code formatting isn't one of those sissy little uptight things only computer science professors care about.  It's an extremely important part of writing code that other people can read.  Much as this may surprise you, the goal of programming is not to write code the computer can understand, the goal is to write code that makes sense to other people (including yourself) that the computer happens to also be able to execute to get the results you want.

Comment: I redid the indention (similar to the way that an auto indenter would, i.e. not caring about intent but rather the syntactic level) in such a way that the problem should be immediately obvious. (I didn't change any other formatting, and the indent was difficult enough because of the error some things are syntactically meaningless).

Comment: @user507879: If you have a [question about code](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code), don't dump it all and say "it doesn't work". Write a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/), tell us what you expect the code to do and what it actually does, including any error messages. Read Jon Skeet's blog post on [writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: And it really is important that if nothing else you are at least constant in your code. There is no reason to use `endl` in some places and `\n` in others. And had you used `{}` everywhere the problem would have been averted. Consistency and Readability are key.

Comment: @user507879: Note that you can easily indent/unindent lines by selecting them in the SO editor and clicking the "101\n010" button.  Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting. Don't neglect to thank the people below if their answers are helpful by up-voting them. If one of their answers is definitive, [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first test for `if (disc == 0.0 && b == 0.0)`, the variable `disc` is uninitialized and hence could have any value whatsoever.  You probably intended to write `if (a == 0.0 && b == 0.0)`...

---

Your mathematics in the imaginary case is more than a little suspect.  If the discriminant is negative, then you need the real part of '-b / 2a' and the imaginary parts are '±√(b² - 4ac)/2a'.  So, maybe you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;

    cout << "Enter a, b and c: ";
    cin  >> a >> b >> c;

    if (a == 0.0 && b == 0.0)
        cout << "The equation is degenerate and has no real roots.\n";
    else if (a == 0.0)
        cout << "The equation has one real root x = " <<  -c/b  << endl;
    else
    {
        double disc = pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c;
        if (disc > 0.0)
        {
            disc = sqrt(disc);
            double root1 = (-b+disc)/(2*a);
            double root2 = (-b-disc)/(2*a);
            cout << "The two real roots are " << root1 << " and " << root2 << endl;
        }
        else if (disc < 0.0)
        {
            double imag = sqrt(-disc)/(2*a);
            double real = (-b)/(2*a);
            cout << "The two complex roots are "
                 << "(" << real << "+" << imag << "i)" << " and "
                 << "(" << real << "-" << imag << "i)" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Both roots are equal to " << -b/(2*a) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample outputs:

```
Enter a, b and c: 2 6 3
The two real roots are -0.633975 and -2.36603

Enter a, b and c: 2 4 3
The two complex roots are (-1+0.707107i) and (-1-0.707107i)

Enter a, b and c: 3 6 3
Both roots are equal to -1
```

Comment: Yes. I indeed did intend to write if(a == 0.0 && b == 0.0). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You missed braces from else if(disc <0.0) hence the next else is orphaned

Comment: And the moral of the story ... **properly format your code** (and it also helps to keep a consistent style -- I prefer to always use braces with conditionals, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double a, b, c, disc, x1, x2, root1, root2, imrt1, imrt2, disc2;
    char i;
    cout<<"Enter a, b and c ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c ;


    if(disc == 0.0 && b == 0.0)
        cout<<"The equation is degenerate and has no real roots. \n";
    else if(a == 0.0)
        cout<<"The equation has one real root x = "<< -c/b <<endl;

    else
    {
        disc =  pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c;
        if (disc > 0.0)
        {
            disc = sqrt(disc);
            root1 = (-b+disc)/(2*a);
            root2 = (-b-disc)/(2*a);
            cout<<"The two real roots are "<<root1<<" and "<<root2<<endl;
        }

        else if(disc < 0.0)
            disc2 =  pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c;
        disc2 = sqrt(disc2);
        imrt1 = (-b+disc2)/(2*a);
        imrt2 = (-b-disc2)/(2*a);
        cout<<"The two imaginary roots are "<<"i"<<imrt1<<" and "<<"i"<<imrt2<<"\n";

        else
            cout<<"Both roots are equal to "<<-b/(2*a)<<endl;
    }//End of compound statement for the outer else

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

here is your code correctly indented (30 sec under notepad++)

and it becomes obvious (as posted by vinothkr) that your missing the braces

> else if(disc < 0.0)

Also Disc in the first test isn't init ...

And I would also recommend to always use {} with if else. Even if it saves 5 secs to not write it, you lose 1/2h debugging any changes.

in comparison

```
int main(){
double a, b, c, disc, x1, x2, root1, root2, imrt1, imrt2, disc2;
char i;
cout<<"Enter a, b and c ";
cin >> a >> b >> c ;

    //Disc never init...
if(disc == 0.0 && b == 0.0){
    cout<<"The equation is degenerate and has no real roots. \n";
}else if(a == 0.0){
    cout<<"The equation has one real root x = "<< -c/b <<endl;

}else{
    disc =  pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c;
    if (disc > 0.0){
        disc = sqrt(disc);
        root1 = (-b+disc)/(2*a);
        root2 = (-b-disc)/(2*a);
        cout<<"The two real roots are "<<root1<<" and "<<root2<<endl;
    }else if(disc < 0.0){
        disc2 =  pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c;
        disc2 = sqrt(disc2);
        imrt1 = (-b+disc2)/(2*a);
        imrt2 = (-b-disc2)/(2*a);
        cout<<"The two imaginary roots are "<<"i"<<imrt1<<" and "<<"i"<<imrt2<<"\n";
    }else{
        cout<<"Both roots are equal to "<<-b/(2*a)<<endl;
    }
}//End of compound statement for the outer else

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thank you. But after a few modifications, when I run the code I get a wrong answer. For  example when I input a=1 and b=2, c=2, I should get the answers; -1+i and -1-i, but when I run my code, it  gives me  0.73205+i and -2.73205

Comment: disc2 =  pow(b,2.0)-4*a*c;
disc2 = sqrt(disc2); unless you have written your own sqrt function you'll have a pb here I think, you can't do a sqrt of a negative number you have to make it absolute or *-1.